# Creating a gif image or movie file from multiple images or with animation of images for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, animated-gif

I search a lot on google but did not find anything appropriate for objective c and iphone.

I want to ask if there is any way to create a single gif(animating) image or a movie file from multiple png  images.

I am having multiple images and I am able to show them in animation like a video.

Now I have to save this either in gif form or in movie format.

Can someone please give me any suggestions or coding help.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please see this example:-https://github.com/arturogutierrez/Animated-GIF-iPhone

Comment: @NitinGohel the link does not contain anything about saving images in gif format.It just shows animating the images which I know.

Comment: You want to create Gif or movie from your device? If you look in the sample code from your Xcode library, there are 2 projects: From A View to A Movie (Mac OS for inspiration) and AVMovieExporter for iOS

Comment: I want to create a gif image but i can create a movie fie then that is also ok but my input is not a movie file there are multiple images that are animating, showing them animated is not a problem but saving them in animating format is the task it can either gif of mov.

Answer (score 0):

You need a utility to create a sprite sheet like [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/tutorials) or [Zwoptex](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker):